# How do I calculate IRR(Internal Rate of Return) of unequal cash flows.

Tags: functional-equations

I have got 4 cash flows:6500;3000;3000;1000. How do I calculate interest rate at which all of them in present are equal to 10 000. 6500/i+3000/i^2+3000/i^3+1000/i^4=1000. Excel computes it by interest rate guess but how do I do it myself?

Comment: Are the cash flows at yearly intervals?  You should be dividing by $(1+i)^n$.  You also have a typo as the final value is listed at $1000$ not $10000$

Comment: yep, sorry for mistake, I was supposed to type 10 000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve this algebraically, just numerically.  You can use any root finding algorithm, bisection, Newton, secant, etc.